# Change the default user on the fly on AWS CLI (Amazon Web Services)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

On my AWS CLI, I have multiple named users, for different account accesses. As part of testing and clients' accesses, we naturally have multiple user keys entered.

To run a AWS CLI command, I understand that the syntax is

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --profile user2
```

The --profile option specifies which named user to use.

My question is: if I wanted to do a bunch of functions on a specific bucket that another user (let's say the name is brixwork, but it's the 3rd user in my config file) it's cumbersome to have to add `--profile brixwork` for each and every line. Is there a way to set the default user for a while without actually having to change the config file to set brixwork as the user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set the AWS_PROFILE variable in your shell environment.

In Windows:

`set AWS_PROFILE=brixwork`

All CLI commands will pick up that user profile without needing to specify it on the command line.

I also use a number of different profiles. In interactive mode scripts, it is helpful to echo the current profile before running the entire command, as a way to make sure you do not run the script under the wrong profile:

```
echo AWS_PROFILE=$AWS_PROFILE
pause
```

The script will confirm the profile it will reference, and I can hit `Ctrl-C` if I do not have the proper one configured.

Comment: This is a good tip. I have been working with the CLI every day for years and I did not know this one.

Comment: @Rodrigo, echoing the profile is a good idea to display to the user. Also, many (maybe most?) AWS CLI commands have a `--dry-run` option which does not execute but will give you an indication of if the resource(s) exist and whether the IAM role under which you execute the command has the necessary privileges.